# How to use uploaded file for saving onto local server in R Shiny?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I want to use the file uploaded by the user and then link it to my other R script. I am unable to get access to the file right now.

```
UI -> fileInput("ghiFile", "Choose GHI File (.csv)", 
accept=c('text/csv',  'text/comma-separated-values','text/plain', '.csv')),
```

The server.r file is empty as I am unable to get access of the file. I want to save the uploaded file on my local machine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

ui.R

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fileInput('target_upload', 'Choose file to upload',
            accept = c(
              'text/csv',
              'text/comma-separated-values',
              '.csv'
            )),
  DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table")

)
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df_products_upload <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$target_upload
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,sep = ";")
    return(df)
  })

  output$sample_table<- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- df_products_upload()
    DT::datatable(df)
  })

}
)
```

Of course, you have to either make sure that the separator is correct, or also use an input for that. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Florian, How would you get this to work inside of a call to an action button. So that the function would run after you press the action button?

Comment: Hi @mikey, what function would you only want to run after an `actionButton` is clicked? Also, the answer to your question will probably be a bit too elaborate for the comments, so please consider opening a new question on SO.